# Yii - Dynamic slug and id capturing

Tags: php, yii

I have a list of data coming from api. From this list - each data has it's own info and can be captured by id.

Below is the code in which when the user click on the link it should redirect to a detailed page of that data

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
        <h3><a href="<?=Yii::app()->createUrl("/resource/view",array($jdvalue->id, $jdvalue->slug)) ?>"><?=$jdvalue->title ?> </a></h3>
        <?php echo ysUtil::truncate(strip_tags($jdvalue->htmlContent, 200)) ?>
   <div class="text-muted margin-top-lg">
        <?=$jdvalue->resourceCategories[0]->typefor ?> - <?=$jdvalue->resourceCategories[0]->title ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

I created action in my module controller

```
public function actionView($id, $slug = null)
{
    $resourceView = HUB::getResource($id);
    if ($slug != $resourceView->slug) {
        return $this->render('view',array('id' => $id, 'slug' => $resourceView->slug));
    }
}
```

I created a generic page to output each data detailed info:

```
<div class="media" id="page-header">
    <div class="pull-right media-middle">
        <a href="#"><img class="media-object" src="<?=$resourceView->imageLogoUrl ?>" alt="logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
         <h1 class="media-heading"><?php echo $resourceView->title ?></h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<hr />
</div>
```

I'm not getting any output on my view page. Would be greatly appreciated if anyone could check the code above.

Comment: looking to you code  i need  to understand where is your problem  . first have you check if the actioView  is reached eg: using a var_dum($id) at the begin of the action? ..

Comment: And check if your if statement `$slug != $resourceView->slug` is valid